# how to get data from datatable using column name

Tags: c#, excel

i have a situation where i load a dataset with excel file.  All the worksheet are loaded as datatable with the appropriate worksheet name as datatable name.  What i am trying to do is get this datatable value using column name.  But i am not get error saying

"Column 'Execute' does not belong to table Sheet1".

While loaded excel to datatabel i have used HDR=YES and IMEX=1.  I also tried with HDR=NO. nothing is working.

below code is to write excel to datatable

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsheet in workbook.Worksheets)
{

    string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM [" + wsheet.Name + "$]";
    OleDbCommand selectCMD1 = new OleDbCommand(sql1, SQLConn);
    SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD1;

    SQLAdapter.Fill(dataset.Tables.Add(wsheet.Name));

 }
```

Data from excel loads to each sheet perfectly. but fetching it by column name is the problem.

any suggestions please

Comment: I'm not sure how much it has to do with it, but I wonder why you are using the `SQLDataAdapter` and not the `OleDbDataAdapter`? I just tried your code but with the `OleDbDataAdapter` and it worked fine (i.e. I got column names).

Comment: actually my code is for oledb, the object i create is like this          OleDbDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();                   it is crazy i know... but thanks, u gave an answer and it worked.

Comment: Right, I see. I thought you might be using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.71).aspx). Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is the code I used, which works fine. I assume you are using Interop to loop through the worksheets to make sure you get them in order.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename +
    "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\"";
DataSet dsValues = new DataSet();

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet wsheet in workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + wsheet.Name + "$]";
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(dsValues.Tables.Add(wsheet.Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the `OleDbDataAdapter` cannot find text in the top cells of each column, then it reverts to the `F1`, `F2`, `F3`... notation for the missing header names. So, for example, if my Excel worksheet looks like this:

```
Header1           Header3
Value1   Value3   Value5
Value2   Value4   Value6
```

Then in the `DataTable` I will get columns called `Header1`, `F2`, `Header3`.

You also need to make sure that the row you designate as the header row has no text in any row above it, otherwise you'll get a bunch of `Fn`-type headers and then other unexpected text as header names. For example:

```
      This is my table
Header1  Header2  Header3
Value1   Value3   Value5
Value2   Value4   Value6
```

Will end up in the DataTable with headers of `This is my table`, `F2`, `F3`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try enumerating (in debug mode and/or console) through `wsheet.Name.Columns` and extract the column names for the table - make sure that it contains the column names that you expect (and in the format that you expect)